# Form alignment/

Tags: angular, laravel

For unknown reasons, these two elements move to the edge of the page.
Is there a reason for the suitcase (onli log and pass)?

```
  <div class="control-group" ng-class="{true: 'error'}[submitted && form.log.$invalid]">

                <label class="control-label" for="log" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Логин:
                <input type="text" name="log" ng-model="mobile"   required ng-pattern="/[A-Za-z]/" id="log" />
                <span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && form.log.$error.required">Обязательное поле.</span>
                    <div class="custom-error"  ng-show="form.log.$error.pattern">Только латинские буквы</div><br>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group2">
            <div class="control-group2" ng-class="{true: 'error'}[submitted && form.pas.$invalid]">
                    <label class="control-label" for="pas" lass="col-sm-3 control-label">Пароль</label>
                    <input type="text" name="pas" ng-model="mobile2"   required ng-pattern="/[A-Za-z]/" id="pas" />
                    <span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && form.pas.$error.required">Обязательное поле.</span>
                    <span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && form.pas.$error.pattern">Только латинские буквы и цифры</span>
                    <div class="custom-error"  ng-show="form.pas.$error.pattern">Только латинские буквы</div><br>
                </div>
            </div>
       <button ng-click='SaveUser()' name="Регистрация"  class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-3">Регисрация</button>
        {{ csrf_field() }}

    </form>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/wapunutexi/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Without CSS definition or live demo it's difficult to answer

Comment: Sorry. http://jsbin.com/wapunutexi/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Instead of linking to jsbin.com, you should create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong.

1. You have multiple class attributes on your label elements
2. You wrap the entire input with the label in the second element
3. You're missing "c" in class in the second element on the label
4. You're using form-group2 as a class, which doesn't exist in Bootstrap, and you have no custom class to support it

I fixed those four things below, and did the same update to your [bin](http://jsbin.com/zobewugafu/edit?html,output):

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="firstName"
             type="phone"
             class="col-sm-3 control-label">Номер телефона </label>
      <input type="text"
             name="phone"
             pattern="[0-9]{2,32}"
             required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="control-group"
           ng-class="{true: 'error'}[submitted && form.log.$invalid]">
        <label for="log"
               class="col-sm-3 control-label">Логин:</label>
        <input type="text"
               name="log"
               ng-model="mobile"
               required
               ng-pattern="/[A-Za-z]/"
               id="log">
        <span class="help-inline"
              ng-show="submitted && form.log.$error.required">Обязательное поле.</span>
        <div class="custom-error"
             ng-show="form.log.$error.pattern">Только латинские буквы</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="control-group"
           ng-class="{true: 'error'}[submitted && form.pas.$invalid]">
        <label for="pas"
               class="col-sm-3 control-label">Пароль</label>
        <input type="text"
               name="pas"
               ng-model="mobile2"
               required
               ng-pattern="/[A-Za-z]/"
               id="pas">
        <span class="help-inline"
              ng-show="submitted && form.pas.$error.required">Обязательное поле.</span>
        <span class="help-inline"
              ng-show="submitted && form.pas.$error.pattern">Только латинские буквы и цифры</span>
        <div class="custom-error"
             ng-show="form.pas.$error.pattern">Только латинские буквы</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```